# C# Checking That 2 Fields in the Same Record Match What User Has Entered e.g Username & Password

Tags: c#, authentication, bindingsource

I want to do a login type form where the Employee enters their EmployeeID and DOB. The code I have so far is to check that both text boxes aren't blank, make sure the EmployeeID exists, but i'm not sure how to check that the DOB for the Employee is the same as what has been entered by them. Some code is below.

```
if ((txtEmployeeID.TextLength != 0) && (txtDOB.TextLength != 0))
{

      employeesBindingSource.Filter = "EmployeeID ='" + txtEmployeeID.Text + "'";

      if (employeesBindingSource.Count > 0)
      {

           // DOES DOB FOR EMPLOYEE MATCH - NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE

      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this we're going to need the Employee DOB variable - replace DataOfBirthVariable with this.

```
if ((txtEmployeeID.TextLength != 0) && (txtDOB.TextLength != 0))
{

      employeesBindingSource.Filter = "EmployeeID ='" + txtEmployeeID.Text + "'";

      if (employeesBindingSource.Count > 0 && DataOfBirthVariable == txtDob)
      {


      }
}
```

Also, it's best practice to use !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmployeeID) instead of .TextLength - just a tip.

Comment: +1 for `!String.IsNullOrEmpty()`. It is extremely efficient at checking string values.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the DoB you trying to match with is a DateTime

```
DateTime enteredDoB;
bool matchedDoB;

if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDOB, out enteredDoB))
{
    matchedDoB = employeeDoB.Equals(enteredDoB);
}
```

See [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a date is getting your employees to input the data in the correct format.

- Jan 1, 1970
- 1/1/1970
- 1/1/70
- 1-1-70
- January 01, '70

All variations of the same thing.

You are going to have to force your employees to input the date field in a format you require.

```
static char DATESPLITTER = '/'; // define this accordingly
static DateTime NODATE = new DateTime(1, 1, 1900);

private DateTime GetDate(string dateValue) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateValue) {
    string[] split = dateValue.Split(DATESPLITTER);
    if (split.Length == 3) {
      int m = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);
      if ((0 < m) && (m < 13)) {
        int d = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
        if ((0 < d) && (d < 32)) {
          int y = Convert.ToInt32(split[2]);
          if ((0 < y) && (y < DateTime.Now.Year)) {
            if (y < 100) y += 2000;
            return new DateTime(m, d, y);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return NODATE;
}
```

That's very similar to a little routing I use in my code.